# Is there a chance that UFOs could be messages from other planets?

Tags: exoplanet, space-probe, identify-this-object

## Description

Lots of people have thought to of seen UFOs *(Unidentified Flying Objects)*, in fact, [more than 83,000](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_reported_UFO_sightings) have been reported **this year alone.** *(and it's only February!)* But most of the time it's just a shooting star or an airplane. But some of the sightings don't seem to be any of the things a UFO is commonly mistook for, but there isn't any evidence supporting if it is really a UFO. I might not be alone on this theory, but I believe the sightings that potentially could be UFOs are messages from the cosmos.

### Question

There may not be much to back up my theory, but I just wish to learn some background knowledge:

> **Are UFOs *(and I guess all the UFO sightings reported, too)* messages from another planet?**

I also believe that if they are messages, they could possibly be responses to [NASA's Voyager spacecrafts](https://voyager.jpl.nasa.gov/), for their purposes were to inform any forms of life out in space what earth is like with the 'Sounds of Earth' music disk attached to it.

Comment: By definition we don't know what UFOs are. So no answer to this can be based on knowledge, only speculation. Hence this question is "primarily opinion based". One thing is clear, there have been no confirmed Alien spacecraft around the Earth. You also misunderstand the purpose of Voyager, and the scale of distance between stars.

Comment: "There's the Elders' aerie. Only Elders go there, but there's nothing there." "Have you ever been there?" "No, of course not." "Then how do you know?" "I don't know that there's no pomegranate tree there. I don't know that there's no laser organ there. I don't know that there's no item of million different kinds there. Does my lack of knowledge of their absence show they are all present?" *(c) Isaac Asimov*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because personal theories about UFOs are not suitable subject matter for Astronomy SE.

Comment: I can't find a suitable site for the question, so I picked Astronomy. If you have a better one, please tell me before close voting. :)

Comment: sigh.....   The Gods Themselves...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**No.**

The purpose of sending a message is to have someone else read it. It defies logic to send a message over light years of space and then have it do anything but broadcast its presence very clearly to anyone who might possibly want to investigate it. If the goal of these UFOs was to tell us something, they wouldn't be such elusive specimens that only appear to specific people at specific times and places, and then disappear without a trace. If UFOs are in fact meant to communicate with humanity, they are indeed rather poorly designed, because they haven't accomplished that goal very well at all!